# Полный список «волшебных» ссылок раздела справки

Tags: поддержка, faq, markdown, ссылки

Наиболее полный список «волшебных» ссылок, который удалось собрать из [ответа Laura](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/134069) и [ответа balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/259214):

- `[help]` - посадочная страница раздела справки того сайта, на котором вы в данный момент находитесь (/help).
- `[help/on-topic]` - ведет на страницу «На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?» (/help/on-topic).
- `[help/dont-ask]` – ведет на страницу «Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?» (/help/dont-ask).
- `[help/behavior]` - ведет на страницу «Какое поведение ожидается от пользователей?» (/help/behavior).
- `[meta-help]` - ведет на страницу «Что такое Мета и как она работает?» (/help/whats-meta).
- `[meta]` – ведет на Мету текущего сайта; текст ссылки совпадает с названием сайта (напр., "Мета Stack Overflow на русском"). Не ведет никуда, если сайт не имеет раздела Мета или сам является Мета-сайтом.
- `[main]` – как [meta], но с точностью до наоборот.
- `[edit]` – ведет на страницу редактирования того сообщения, к которому сделан комментарий, то есть /posts/{id}/edit. Текст ссылки – «edit» (чувствительно к регистру).
- `[tour]` и `[meta-tour]` – ведут на страницу сайта «Тур» (для Меты не существует отдельного «Тура»). Текст ссылки – «tour» (чувствительно к регистру). Также поддерживаются используемые ранее `[about]` и `[meta-about]`.
- `[ask]`, `[answer]`, `[mcve]` – ведут на страницы «Как задать хороший вопрос?»/«Как написать хороший ответ?»/«Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример?».
- `[so]`, `[su]`, `[sf]`, `[metase]`, `[a51]`, `[se]` – ведут на страницу заданного сайта ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com), [Stack Exchange portal](http://stackexchange.com/)). Текст ссылки – название сайта.
- `[ru.so]`, `[pt.so]`, `[jp.so]` и другие – ведут на локализованные сайты Stack Overflow ([Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) и т.п.).
- `[something.se]` – ведет на сайт something.stackexchange.com, если он существует. Текст ссылки – название сайта. Для Ask Ubuntu используйте `[ubuntu.se]`, `[meta.something.se]` ведет на Мета-сайт.
- `[chat]` – ведет на чат текущего сайта (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ для SO, http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ для Meta SE, http://chat.stackexchange.com/ для всех остальных сайтов, последняя ссылка показывает список активных комнат для сайта), текст ссылки выглядит следующим образом: «{site name} Chat».

Если вы обнаружите справочные материалы, не вошедшие в наш список, добавьте, пожалуйста, ссылки на них к данному сообщению.

---

Это свободный перевод публикации «[Complete list of help center magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/)»

Comment: проверка `[ru.so]` > [ru.so]

Comment: это только на [meta]? [meta]???

Comment: @Grundy  Поясните, пожалуйста, не понял вопрос.

Comment: я не понял как это работает :-) я думал когда пишешь `[meta]` или что-то подобное из списка - то в это место должна была ссылка вставляться.

Comment: @Grundy Да, совершенно верно. Только для Меты это будет `[main]`  –> [main].

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, [main]

Comment: во! для маин сработало. интересно [chat]

Comment: попробовал на ruSO в комментариях - вроде не работает, а нет, вру - работают!!!

Comment: Проверка 2: [mcve].

Comment: @NickVolynkin Видимо, не все страницы справки работают: [help/on-topic].

Comment: `[mvce]` работает (по крайней мере на главном сайте), добавил