# Добавить волшебную ссылку на MCVE

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, markdown, ссылки

В дополнение к этому: [Полный список «волшебных» ссылок раздела справки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2709/181472)

Очень хочу, чтобы у нас появилась ссылка `[mcve]` -> [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Будет очень уместно использовать её как дополнение к комментариям под многочисленными вопросами "почему у меня не работает ...", не имеющим ни строчки кода.

На Stack Overflow уже работает. Удивительно, что на локализованных сайтах - нет.

Comment: ссылка на [mcve], да, не работает, но в одной из статей про нее вроде писали чтобы работала

Comment: @Grundy ага, точно )

Comment: забавно, но [вот тут](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) говорят, что все добавлено

Comment: что интересно = на английском SO работает эта ссылка

Comment: MCVE -- вообще, что это такое?

Comment: Подскажите, были ли замечены еще какие–то ссылки, которые не работают на  Stack Overflow на русском?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вроде нет. Эта у нас и не должна работать, она заявлена как только для [so] в том самом ответе balpha.

Comment: @avp это [Как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Мы и есть Stack Overflow :) Надо поправить просто.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, понятно. А причем здесь аббревиатура MCVE? Это что-то вроде *minimal completed verified example*?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Готово! Попросил подправить, чтобы тянули строку на русском.

Comment: @avp, да это именно она :)