# Волшебные ссылки не работают в ответах, только в комментариях

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, ответы

Попробовал воспользоваться [волшебными ссылками](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2709/) при написании ответа и обнаружил, что система распознаёт их только в комментариях:

[help] [meta] [main] [so] [ask] [answer] [mcve]

Это баг или фича?

Или это не нужно? Мне сложно оценить востребованность. Самому впервые такое потребовалось.

Comment: а какая из этих ссылок потребовалась в ответе?

Comment: @Grundy [mcve] в конце ответа http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529080/208926

Comment: [_Add data.SE style “magic links” **to comments**_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000) = основная тема. Поэтому вопросы должны отпасть :)

Comment: @Grundy приветствую. Я понимаю, что большинство программистов знает английский язык. Но у нас, всё-таки, русскоязычное сообщество SO. Поэтому объяснения желательно должны быть на русском языке, а не отсылка на enSO. Например, я не знаю английского, потому и сижу на ruSO, а не на enSO. Мне тоже интересно узнать ответ на вопрос ТС, но понять из вашей ссылки я ничего не могу. :)

Comment: @intro94, _to comments_ которые я выделил в ссылке, как бы говорят что добавление идет к коментариям

Comment: @Grundy, Спасибо за пояснение. =_=  То есть, эти *магические ссылки* работают только в комментариях?

Comment: @intro94, то есть их _просили_ только для комментариев :-)

Comment: @Grundy понятно... :)

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо за объяснение. Можете разместить свой комментарий как ответ? Хочу отметить его как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grundy объяснил в комментариях к вопросу, что волшебные ссылки [созданы именно для комментариев](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/). Они помогают добавлять ссылки, которые чаще всего приходится показывать новичкам и нарушителям порядка:

> Интересно, в скольких комментариях вы набирали вот такое:
>
> ```
> [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com)
> ```
>
> Лично я уже устал это делать. Можем мы завести себе волшебные ссылки как на data.stackexchange.com? (как отдушину для усталых рук)

Answer (score 5):

Ответы призваны содержать *ответы*, пардон за тавтологию. Если вам в ответе понадобилось объяснять правила, понадобилось обсуждать написание вопроса, то это не ответ, а комментарий.

Что касается конкретно вашего ответа, то там сейчас приписка "UPD. Отредактировал заголовок вопроса и понял, что мой ответ не годится" и MCVE, сделанный за автора вопроса — вообще непонятно, что происходит.

Comment: Что касается **UPD**, то тут всё предельно ясно. Вы посмотрите правку вопроса, которую внёс Глеб. Изначально он не правильно понял вопрос и дал ответ. После того как внёс правку, сделал вопрос более понятным, он понял, что ответ не подходит. Но в таком случае следовало бы ответ удалить, а не вносить **UPD**. Ну это моё мнение... :)

Comment: @Discord По отношению к ответам на основном сайте согласен, но в ответах на Мете волшебные ссылки были бы кстати. Тем более, что руки привыкают их набирать.

Comment: @intro94 Спасибо за объяснение ситуации. Не знаю, удалять или нет. Задал [отдельный вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3118/).