# MCVE, сделанный за автора вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Цитирую в теме [слова Discord](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3115/208926), потому что они точно отражают проблему:

Дал развёрнутый [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529080/208926). После этого отредактировал заголовок вопроса и понял, что вопрос касается ситуации, с которой моё решение перестаёт справляться.

Мой ответ оказался неправильным, но превратился в [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) с пояснениями.

Если просто удалить ответ, пропадёт полезная информация.
Если перенести сниппет и пояснения в вопрос, то влезу на территорию автора. 
Удалять сниппет, чтобы поставить фиддл в комментарии к вопросу... Так ведь сниппет нагляднее и время экономит. Его можно скопировать в свой ответ, чтобы проиллюстрировать совсем другое решение.

Как лучше поступить с ответом?

Answer (score 8):

Если ваш ответ не является ответом, то его следует удалить. Если есть возможность улучшить вопрос, то следует это сделать.

Из чисто практических соображений, учитывая, что ваш код значительно превышает объём исходного вопроса, я бы перенёс код в вопрос, но с горизонтальной разделительной чертой и отметкой жирным текстом, что далее следует не текст автора вопроса, а ваш.

По вкусу можно упростить ваш код до настоящего MCVE и выкинуть jQuery, который там совершенно не нужен. Но это так, если делать больше нечего.

Comment: Если дополнять вопрос приемлемо, то вариант с чертой - это выход, спасибо. Поясните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду под "выкинуть jQuery". Вот [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/Lo276ban/).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Много кода, не имеющего к вопросу никакого отношения. См. https://jsfiddle.net/z1x4rLzf/2/

Answer (score 2):

Я за то, чтобы оставить ответ с явным описанием того, что осталось сделать.