# Где взять 9 символов на [mcve]?

Tags: поддержка, нытьё, комментарии

При попытке сделать комментарий из "[волшебной ссылки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2709/181472)" `[mcve]`, надо написать ещё 9 символов:

[image: Надо ещё 9 символов]

Comment: Щито поделать, десу. Системе всё равно, что вы там пишете. У комментария минимум 15 символов должно быть. Так что пишите `идите читать [mcve]`. :)

Comment: или там `Будьте добры, предоставьте [mcve]`. Вы что курсовую работу никогда не писали? Отличный опыт по дописыванию N символов к тексту )

Comment: Вы же знаете про приём с RTL-LTR, к чему вопросы? :)

Comment: @Discord, его копипастить замучаешься...

Answer (score 10):

Скорее всего, если есть необходимость данной волшебной ссылки, автор вопроса не до конца понимает правила сообщества. Как мне кажется, сухая отправка к справе без каких–либо комментариев не многим лучше отправке в поисковик, и может оттолкнуть человека. Вы всегда можете:

- добавить конкретные рекомендации, по исправлению недостатков вопроса;
- быть вежливы.

Например,

```
Оформите ваш код в виде кода, а также обратите внимание как написать «[mcve]».
```

Comment: А в первом комментарии что?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не понял вопрос, поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня на скриншоте не только поле, но ещё и пара комментариев. Первый из них уже содержит соответствующую фразу.

Answer (score 4):

Когда налетаю на это ограничение, воспринимаю его как стимул писать литературным языком. Добавлять к ссылкам глаголы, пояснять выводы, превращать реплики в законченные фразы.

Недостающие 9 символов:

> Сделайте [mcve]

Comment: "Сделайте Минимальный" - заглавная буква :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Мне кажется, заглавная буква даже кстати в начале ссылки с длиннющим названием. Похоже на название главы в содержании электронной книги. Кстати, волшебная ссылка на тур позволяет управлять регистром первой буквы: [tour], [Tour].

Comment: Что-то не то у второй с языком ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, [уже наябедничал](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3132/) на неё :)

Answer (score 3):

Недостаточно волшебных ссылок! Нужно больше волшебных ссылок!

```
[ask], [mcve], [help/on-topic]!
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Разумеется, обычное человеческое сообщение, адресованное непосредственно автору вопроса или ответа, нельзя заменить никаким количеством ссылок.